# The normalizer of the unipotent radical of P in GL(n,F)

Tags: matrices, group-theory

I am trying to find a way to show that normalizer of the unipotent radical of a parabolic subgroup in GL(n,F) is in fact the parabolic subgroup. A parabolic subgroup of GL(n,F) is a subgroup that stabilizes a flag in vector space of column vectors of length n with entries from the field F, while the unipotent radical subgroup is the subgroup of this parabolic subgroup consisting of those matrices that induce the identity transformation on Vi/Vi-1 where (V1,...,Vn) is our flag.
So in our normalizer we would have invertible n x n matrices with entries from F for which the conjugate of some matrix from unipotent radical by this matrices from GL(n,F) is again a matrix from the unipotent radical. Therefore, we have to show that this matrices for which this would be true also fix our flag (V1,...,Vn). Does anyone know how this should be done?

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: An element $g$ in the normalizer of $P$ must map $V_1$ to a $1$-subspace on which $P$ induces the identity. But $V_1$ is the only such subspace, so $g$ maps $V_1$ to $V_1$. Now prove similarly that $g$ maps $V_i$ to $V_i$ for $i=2,\ldots,n$, showing that $g$ lies in the parabolic subgroup.

Comment: @DerekHolt but I would need to show that this is true for an element g in the normalizer of unipotent radical, not of a parabolic subgroup, or did I miss something?

Comment: Sorry, I misread your notation, and I was using $P$ to denote the unipotent radical, and I was explaining how to show that $g \in N_G(P)$ lies in the corresponding parabolic subgroup.

Comment: Oh, great, however I don't understand why would V1 be the only such subspace?